# CSS sub-menu overlay issue

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover, submenu

I'm trying to set up this 2 column menu that is side by side with each of the columns submenus opening to a different side. The left menu is working correctly, and the submenu buttons are clickable, but the right menu submenu items are located under the left menu elements. I tried using z-index, which worked, but made the left-menu items not clickable (hover did not work as well). Please see http://kink.cz/najforever/index_copy.html for reference.
Could you please suggest how I can have the right menu submenu items shown correctly?
Your help is much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class='people'>
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li class='active has-sub' id='fake'><a href='#'><span>A fake artist</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='active has-sub' id='danny'><a href='#'><span>Danny Rose Fashion</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='active has-sub' id='heels'><a href='#'><span>Heels in Prague</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='active has-sub' id='hodanajan'><a href='#'><span>Hodanajan</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='active has-sub' id='jakub'><a href='#'><span>Jakub Mařík</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Web</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id='cssmenu2'>
    <ul>
        <li class='active has-sub' id='kaa'><a href='#'><span>Kaa Glo</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='active has-sub' id='pau'><a href='#'><span>Paulinemma</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='active has-sub' id='red'><a href='#'><span>Red Poppy Stories</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='active has-sub' id='kisic'><a href='#'>Sandra Kisic</a>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='active has-sub' id='aesthet'><a href='#'><span>The Aesthet</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* ===========================
   ====== Name Menu Right ====== 
   =========================== */

#cssmenu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align:left
}

#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
  float: left;
}

#cssmenu ul li {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 200px;
  z-index: 598;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  float: none;
  right:250px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: -2px;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  top: 1px;
  left: 99%;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  margin-top: 1px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  font-weight: normal;
}

/* Custom CSS Styles Menu Right*/
#cssmenu {
  width: 130px;
  background: white;
  font-family: 'Oxygen Mono', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  zoom: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  float:right;
  margin-left:5px;
}
#cssmenu:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right:5px;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  width: 130px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  width: 130px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: black;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: black;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active a {
  background: white;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover a {
  background: white;
}
#cssmenu li {
  position: relative;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.first {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.last {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
    margin-left:2px;
    text-align:right;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  color: black;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
  background: black;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > a {
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  border-right: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li {
  text-align: right;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  content: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.first {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.last {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* ===========================
   ====== Name Menu Left ====== 
   =========================== */

#cssmenu2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align:right;
}

#cssmenu2 ul,
#cssmenu2 ul li,
#cssmenu2 ul ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu2 ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
  float: left;
}

#cssmenu2 ul li {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu2 ul li.hover,
#cssmenu2 ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:left;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul li {
  float: none;
  margin-left:4px;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul ul {
  top: -2px;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu2 ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul {
  top: 1px;
  left: 99%;
}
#cssmenu2 ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul {
  margin-top: 1px;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul li {
  font-weight: normal;
}

/* Custom CSS Styles Menu Left*/
#cssmenu2 {
  width: 130px;
  background: white;
  font-family: 'Oxygen Mono', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  zoom: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  float:right;
  margin-left:5px;
}
#cssmenu2:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu2:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu2 a {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right:5px;
}
#cssmenu2 > ul {
  width: 130px;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul {
  width: 130px;
}
#cssmenu2 > ul > li > a {
  border-right: 4px solid black;
  color: black;
}
#cssmenu2 > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: black;
}
#cssmenu2 > ul > li.active a {
  background: white;
}
#cssmenu2 > ul > li a:hover,
#cssmenu2 > ul > li:hover a {
  background: white;
}
#cssmenu2 li {
  position: relative;
}

#cssmenu2 ul ul li.first {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul li.last {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  background:white;
  margin-top:-2px;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul {
    margin-left:2px;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul a:hover {
  color: black;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul li {
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul li:hover > a {
  background: black;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu2.align-right > ul > li > a {
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  border-right: none;
}
#cssmenu2.align-right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu2.align-right li {
  text-align: right;
}

#cssmenu2.align-right ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  content: none;
}
#cssmenu2.align-right ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu2.align-right ul ul li.first {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
}
#cssmenu2.align-right ul ul li.last {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
}
#cssmenu2.align-right ul ul {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* ===========================
   ====== Contact Form ====== 
   =========================== */

input, textarea {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    width: 400px;
    color: #999999;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;     
}

textarea {
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    max-width: 400px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

input:hover, textarea:hover,
input:focus, textarea:focus {
    border-color: 1px solid #C9C9C9;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 8px; 
}

.form label {
    color: #999999;
}

/*  Submit Button */

.submit input {
    width: 100px; 
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #474E69; 
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hopefully It will work, I have checked @MarianRehak..**

just remove `z-index` from

```
#cssmenu2 ul{}
```

and add this class

```
#cssmenu2 ul li:hover ul {
    z-index: 999999 !important;
}
```

**Rest you can play with the position.. the basic issue will be resolved now..**

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works great.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your CSS. Changes applied on many places. You'll need to apply some more CSS to make menu look same is the left menu.

```css
#cssmenu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align:left
}

#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
  float: left;
}

#cssmenu ul li {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 598;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: -2px;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
  display:block;
  z-index:99999;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  top: 1px;
  right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  margin-top: 1px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  font-weight: normal;
}

/* Custom CSS Styles Menu Right*/
#cssmenu {
  width: 130px;
  background: white;
  font-family: 'Oxygen Mono', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  zoom: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  float:right;
  margin-left:5px;
}
#cssmenu:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right:5px;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  width: 130px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  width: 130px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: black;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: black;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active a {
  background: white;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover a {
  background: white;
}
#cssmenu li {
  position: relative;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.first {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.last {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
    margin-left:2px;
    text-align:right;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  color: black;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
  background: black;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > a {
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  border-right: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li {
  text-align: right;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  content: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.first {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.last {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* ===========================
   ====== Name Menu Left ====== 
   =========================== */

#cssmenu2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align:right;
}

#cssmenu2 ul,
#cssmenu2 ul li,
#cssmenu2 ul ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu2 ul {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

#cssmenu2 ul li {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu2 ul li.hover,
#cssmenu2 ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:left;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul li {
  float: none;
  margin-left:4px;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul ul {
  top: -2px;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu2 ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul {
  top: 1px;
  left: 99%;
}
#cssmenu2 ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul {
  margin-top: 1px;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul li {
  font-weight: normal;
}

/* Custom CSS Styles Menu Left*/
#cssmenu2 {
  width: 130px;
  background: white;
  font-family: 'Oxygen Mono', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  zoom: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  float:right;
  margin-left:5px;
}
#cssmenu2:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu2:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu2 a {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right:5px;
}
#cssmenu2 > ul {
  width: 130px;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul {
  width: 130px;
}
#cssmenu2 > ul > li > a {
  border-right: 4px solid black;
  color: black;
}
#cssmenu2 > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: black;
}
#cssmenu2 > ul > li.active a {
  background: white;
}
#cssmenu2 > ul > li a:hover,
#cssmenu2 > ul > li:hover a {
  background: white;
}
#cssmenu2 li {
  position: relative;
}

#cssmenu2 ul ul li.first {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul li.last {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  background:white;
  margin-top:-2px;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul {
    margin-left:2px;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul a:hover {
  color: black;
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul li {
}
#cssmenu2 ul ul li:hover > a {
  background: black;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu2.align-right > ul > li > a {
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  border-right: none;
}
#cssmenu2.align-right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu2.align-right li {
  text-align: right;
}

#cssmenu2.align-right ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  content: none;
}
#cssmenu2.align-right ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu2.align-right ul ul li.first {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
}
#cssmenu2.align-right ul ul li.last {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
}
#cssmenu2.align-right ul ul {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* ===========================
   ====== Contact Form ====== 
   =========================== */

input, textarea {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    width: 400px;
    color: #999999;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;     
}

textarea {
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    max-width: 400px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

input:hover, textarea:hover,
input:focus, textarea:focus {
    border-color: 1px solid #C9C9C9;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 8px; 
}

.form label {
    color: #999999;
}

/*  Submit Button */

.submit input {
    width: 100px; 
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #474E69; 
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;     
}
```

```html
<div class='people'>
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li class='active has-sub' id='fake'><a href='#'><span>A fake artist</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='active has-sub' id='danny'><a href='#'><span>Danny Rose Fashion</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='active has-sub' id='heels'><a href='#'><span>Heels in Prague</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='active has-sub' id='hodanajan'><a href='#'><span>Hodanajan</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='active has-sub' id='jakub'><a href='#'><span>Jakub Mařík</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Web</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id='cssmenu2'>
    <ul>
        <li class='active has-sub' id='kaa'><a href='#'><span>Kaa Glo</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='active has-sub' id='pau'><a href='#'><span>Paulinemma</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='active has-sub' id='red'><a href='#'><span>Red Poppy Stories</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='active has-sub' id='kisic'><a href='#'>Sandra Kisic</a>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='active has-sub' id='aesthet'><a href='#'><span>The Aesthet</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try changing this class.. it will work.

```
#cssmenu ul ul {
    margin-left: 113px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Let me know any issues

Comment: Thanks, could you please clarify why would I want to change the margin-left property? I don't think it will fix the overlay issue.

Comment: To be more specific, I would like to have the right submenu items shown on the left side from the menu, where the left menu is located. So it should be more or less where it is now, but over the menu items, so it is visible. The code works here on stackoverflow (when clicking  run code snippet, but somehow does not work the same way on my web).

Comment: I have answered the fix below. please check and let me know. @MarianRehak